# Get log of all queries being run on a Oracle database

Tags: oracle, logging, oracle10g

How can i get a log of all queries being run on the oracle 10g database running on my Linux server?

Comment: Do you literally just want a list of the statements being executed? Or do you want more information about who's running the queries, how often, etc?

Comment: Use `v$sql` for a current snapshot, or if you have an enterprise edition with the performance pack use the `DBA_HIST_xxx` views

Comment: @APC it will be v nice to get more information like you said.

Comment: if you want all the queries, a system wide trace might be the only way to go - but you might get what you asked for

Comment: FWIW, questions like this may be better suited for the DBA site rather than StackOverflow.